# Using QT and QML how to rotate a mesh about a specific origin

Tags: qt, 3d, rotation, qml, qtquick3d

I have imported several 3D meshes from blender to form a human figure and I want to rotate the arm-meshes about a specific origin point so that it will look like the normal movement of an arm. In order to display the mesh, it needs to be included in the `Entity` class although I can not use the `Rotation` property inside the entity class which has a property of `origin` in itself. If there is a way to rotate meshes about specific point?

Below is my code. I have to rotate the shoulder mesh, but it does not rotate about a specific origin point so its rotation does not match up with normal body movement

```
Entity{
    Mesh {
        id: rightShoulder
        source: "objects/RightShoulder2.obj"
    }

    Transform {
        id: RightShoulderTransform
        Scale { scale3D: Qt.vector3d(1.5, 1, 1.5) }

        Rotate {
           id:RightShoulderRotation
           angle: headSlider.value
           axis: Qt.vector3d(0, 1, 0)
        }
        Entity {
           id: headEntity
           components: [rightShoulder, material, RightShoulderTransform]
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to solve it.
Center of Blender editor space  is "origin" point of your object.
Like this:["origin"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrwFe.png)

Green point in mesh is origin point of selected object